# Xamarin MvvmCross - MvxFragment communicating with MvxActionBarActivity

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I currently have a project in Xamarin and I am using MvvmCross. I have an MvxActionBarActivity that hosts MvxFragments. Now when I want to close the entire MvxActionBarActivity, the event begins in the Fragment and I want to tell the MvxActionBarActivity to close. Calling Close(this) in the fragment viewmodel is not working.

I have considered using MvxMessegner to send message from one viewmodel to the other but due to the relationship of a fragment and an activity I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you really want: do you want to close the activity so another activity will show, do you want to move the activity to the background, or do you want to close the whole app?

One thing i would recommend is to look at the latest example: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

The MvxActionBarActivity is deprecated so it would be better to use Toolbar now.

Comment: Sorry just close the current activity so the previous activity in the stack can resume, also remove the current activity and fragment references from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to close an `Activity` you need to call `Finish()`. This will close that activity and go back to that what is on the backstack.

If you want to call that from your viewmodel you should use a custom presenter: http://gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-navigating-android-with-fragments/